# aggregate a few rows and display in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, aggregate

I have a table `ZXC`

```
select NAME, MONTH, YEAR, DEPT, MONTHVAL, YEARVAL from ZXC
```

the column `MONTHVAL` has some values. I want to aggregate some rows based on the combination of name, dept and month, and display the aggregated value in `YEARVAL` column.

for example, if i have the table

```
Name   Month  Year Dept Monthval  Yearval

BLAKE   Jan   2011 100   124.542    0 
KING    Feb   2011 200   234.542    0 
KING    Jan   2011 200   27764.464  0 
BLAKE   March 2011 100   0          0 
BLAKE   Feb   2011 400   0          0 
SCOTT   Jan   2011 500   24564.464  0 
KING    March 2011 200   1265.542   0 
KING    April 2011 200   1065.542   0
```

then i want to see the result as

```
Name   Month  Year Dept Monthval  Yearval

BLAKE   Jan   2011 100  124.542    124.542
KING    Jan   2011 200  27764.464  27764.464  
SCOTT   Jan   2011 500  24564.464  24564.464 
KING    Feb   2011 200  234.542    27999.006 
BLAKE   Feb   2011 100  0          124.542 
KING    March 2011 200  1265.542   29264.548 
BLAKE   March 2011 100  0          124.542 
KING    April 2011 200  1065.542   30330.09
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
SELECT name
     , dept
     , year
     , SUM( monthval ) yearval
FROM   zxc
GROUP  BY name
        , dept
        , year;
```

This would produce a total of monthly values for each year. I am not really sure if this is 
what you needed, but looks like it to me.

You can make it even fancier by using `ROLLUP()` or `CUBE()` functions in `GROUP BY` functions (multiple level of aggregations).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like:

```
select NAME,
       MONTH,
       YEAR,
       DEPT,
       MONTHVAL,
       SUM(MONTHVAL) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR) YEARVAL
  from ZXC
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output, it seems like you want a running total for every person. Basically, the following query shows a general solution for this:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  Month,
  Year,
  Dept,
  Monthval,
  SUM(Monthval) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Dept ORDER BY Year, Month) AS Yearval
FROM ZXC
```

But there might be a problem with ordering by `Month`, because the months seems to be stored as names in your table, not as numbers. I would then change the above like this:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  Month,
  Year,
  Dept,
  Monthval,
  SUM(Monthval) OVER (
    PARTITION BY Name, Dept
    ORDER BY TO_DATE(Year || '-' || SUBSTR(Month, 1, 3), '-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
  ) AS Yearval
FROM ZXC
```